# Analytics Service/API for plain java desktop applications

Tags: java, google-analytics, analytics

I am looking for a analytics service like keen.io or google analytics for plain desktop applications.
google analytics only provides a android sdk which is not usable with a java sdk.
Anyone knows a good service for this?
We just want to track user events on our application (selected product, number of pictures, ...)

Thanks
Sebastian

One more important functionality is that we can track a user session.
All events must be assignable to a user / session

Comment: you can track what ever you want with the measurement protocol. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Comment: But there is no sdk right? just logging plain events with http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Android, IOS and windows SDKs along with the normal analytics.js JavaScript snippet.   For inserting data in to Google Analytics.

You are correct there is no SDK for pure Java.

That being said you can do this on your own using Pure HTTP Posts or HTTP GETs via the [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
```

PayLoad

```
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
```

The [client id and user id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#user) parameters will allow you to control user and session data.