# Google Analytics 4 for desktop Java application

Tags: java, google-analytics, analytics, desktop

I am trying to track usage of a desktop Java application using Google Analytics 4 (GA4).  There are some [older articles like this one for Universal Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713840/analytics-service-api-for-plain-java-desktop-applications) but I don't see anything for Google Analytics 4.  Basically, I want to do a GET of a web page that has the normal GA4 script inserts.  Then I can use Google Analytics to track usage of the desktop application.  I can see that I might have to specify the user agent header in the GET but what is appropriate for a desktop application?  The bigger problem is that a GET is not enough because the GA4 script code in the HTML file needs to somehow execute in the desktop application, such as if in an embedded IFrame.  Or, is there a GA4 API that should be called differently?  I am using Java 8 and will be updating to 11 or later soon.  I have in the past used the Swing `JEditorPane` to view HTML but did not use it with `<script>`.  The performance hit on the desktop application needs to be minimal (less than a second).  My initial work was misleading because GA4 showed my browser views of the HTML page, not the desktop application.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to run a complete website in order to properly sequence the javascript which then ends of making some really simple javascript calls is, literally, a Rube Goldberg contraption. **Massively** overengineered, requiring tons of future maintenance headache and inflating your application's footprint both on disk and in memory by hundreds of megabytes, not to mention a significant increase in exposure to security issues by shipping all that.

Thus, this is a slam dunk X/Y problem:

- You have a problem where you want to track your desktop app's usage online. (This is X)
- You thought: I know! Websites have this GA4 thing that sounds like what I want so I'll just use that!
- ... but... I have some questions about how to do this (this is the Y).

The true answer to your question is to mention that the middle bullet there **was incorrect**. That's not a good idea at all, and hence, your question about Y is irrelevant. What you should really be doing is asking question X: I have a desktop app, how do I track its use?

So, let me answer that.

### But first.. legal! Yaaay!

The EU has made fairly clear that its laws about privacy (GDPR and friends) disallow things like GA4 without clear and explicit permission from the user whose data you are gathering. Schrems2 (a court judgement, you can search for it if you want details) effectively (it's legal, I'm oversimplifying) says that a non-EU-quartered company **cannot** legally claim to uphold GDPR in such a way as to avoid having to ask your users for clear permission, given that a non-EU-quarted company cannot be reasonably asked to choose for EU laws if a local government *orders* them to do a conflicting act (i.e. a direct order from the CIA or whatnot to give them direct access to the data in google's GA4 tracking database).

(Note that your original plan of shipping an entire browser environment *just* to run some javascript wouldn't magically relieve these legal issues, it's not a feasible solution here).

This adds up to giving you one of four options:

- You ask the user for permission. In my experience, a standalone desktop app explaining that you cannot use it unless you allow it to contact GA4's servers or some other third-party tracking system, is going to cause you a *ton* of vehemently complaining users, but, it's an option.
- You drop the topic entirely. No tracking.
- You write your own tracking framework and ask permission for *that*, which is likely to result in far less issues. Or, you set up a system such that the user can reasonably be expected that some basic tracking is going on. If your app requires a login, and you manage the tracking of this yourself, you're possibly in the clear and don't need GDPR or cookie-style warnings and permission prompts. This really isn't particularly difficult, but it does mean you need to maintain your own server or at least endpoint (say, with an AWS lambda responder on it to keep costs and sysops needs to a minimum).
- You ignore this advice and risk some nasty issues. If you live in the EU I *throughly* recommend against this course of action. If you don't, you could risk it; it'll be illegal in the EU most likely but as a tiny company/individual I doubt they're going to care. Still, this is tech debt of a different sort: If ever your app becomes popular or you're in talks to sell it someplace, ignoring this issue is going to cause some fairly significant headache at the very least.

The point of GDPR and co is more or less to put an end to the casual 'eh, I will just track everything because who knows maybe it'll be cool to look through all those stats and perhaps I can sell it off later' attitude that the tech world has adopted in the past decade, i.e. - yes, this law is designed to stop precisely what you're asking, so it's sensible that you're now thinking: What the... this sounds like such a drag!

Yes. That is the point.

### Okay I wanna do it anyway with GA4!

Okay, your funeral. GA4 has its own API. The GA4 script stuff you load on a webpage simply uses that API; there is no need to use *that javascript* to use that API, you can just use it directly.

A large part of the GA4 update is the very legal stuff mentioned above: You can't just send a 'ping' anymore, you need to first set up a scheme to indicate that the user whose data you are collecting has given consent.

The GA4 plugin for iPhone and android development can do that for you. So can that GA4 javascript stuff for websites. You'll have to trawl the documentation of GA4 if there are ways to do this if you aren't a website, aren't an android app, and aren't an iPhone app. Possibly, there just isn't - a lot of their pages still talk about FLOC and have some dubious claims about the legality of consent-less GA4 if they avoid using cookies, which is precisely the kind of 'Lets stick to the letter of the law and completely ignore the spirit; it works in the US, surely the EU is the same' stuff that american companies keep falling for.

Point is, google analytics gets up to all sorts of complicated shenanigans to dance around or comply with legal issues, all of which indicates that your proposed solution is just not going to work. You truly have to eliminate the entire browser and then fake the consent clicks which is now you intentionally attempting to break privacy laws, even for a small outfit that's definitely not a good idea.

[Here is a blog post by Revenera about it (they mostly recommend the same way: Do not use GA4 for desktop apps)](https://www.revenera.com/blog/software-monetization/tracking-desktop-applications-with-google-analytics-what-you-should-know/). Then again, they wanna sell you their solution for tracking desktop apps, so this is a bit like an apple salesperson telling you that oranges are no good. Sure. They would say that. Still, some good info in there that explains in more detail how GA4 doesn't really match up to desktop tracking needs.

The general API for anything to ping a GA4 account was called the 'Measurement Protocol'. [Read the docs on the MP for GA4 here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). Note that the docs call out:

> The intent of the Measurement Protocol is to augment automatic collection via gtag, Tag Manager, and Google Analytics for Firebase not to replace them.

Further highlighting how GA4 really isn't meant for this.

### Setting up your own

This really isn't particularly complicated. You can avoid legal issues by tracking in a way that isn't personal. For example, have your own app generate a unique ID once and store it someplace local, and send that - that's very unlikely to be a legal issue. If you want to track location, store only very broad geo-ip info (country and not much more than that), and consider using tricks such as hashing content to be able to differentiate different things (example, differentiate IP addresses), without having to figure out if the data you are storing is considered private (and IP addresses probably *are* considered private especially if there is no plausible reason a user can intuit that the app clearly must be storing this for its normal functioning).

You'll need a server to do all this on, but many IAAS platforms including AWS (Amazon Web Services) have a free tier, and most have an 'on demand code execution' system, such as AWS Lambda, which means you don't need to have a server running nor maintain (i.e. apply security patches) to that server. This should keep costs low-to-0, though you'll have to figure out how to program it all.

There are numerous tutorials on how to use java+AWS lambda, and how do make dead-simple REST APIs with e.g. [Spark](https://sparkjava.com).

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid there might be a land mine waiting on this one.  One reason for the tracking is to know how many users are using a specific version of the application so that we can better help them transition to new versions (captive audience with an agreement).  And, some software is paid for by government funding and we want to justify the continued investment in the software by documenting how many users, ideally with some geographic information (county or scale for funding discussions, etc.).  I'll ponder the legal and technical options but maybe GA4 is not the answer.

Comment: Also...I agree that GA4 is complex and overengineered. I don't have time to figure it all out but we do have government clients and nonprofit funders that want analytics on use and impact and GA4 is the default solution right now.  We use AWS and develop REST web services so I will think about a custom simple solution.  I have looked at the GA4 API docs and they are painful.  The point about Google doing things to evade privacy requirements helps explain the complexity.  Hopefully this article helps out a few people.  I'll try to post an accepted solution in the future.

Comment: I'm not saying GA4 is complex and overengineered. I'm saying loading up a built-in browser-esque javascript engine to run GA4 from a desktop app is complex and overengineered.

Comment: Ahhh.  OK.  I get what you are saying.  I agree with most of what you have said.  I do work that collects environmental data from remote sensors.  We use a "heartbeat" transmission to check-in and pass back sensor information such as the GPS clock time.  We also use Zabbix to monitor systems.  What I need has similarities.  I just though that GA4 might be a ready-built solution for applications but as you have pointed out it requires a more thoughtful solution.